# why my redis command keys does not block my other operation

Tags: redis, redis-cli

form many blog, i learn that the redis command `keys *` may block the redis server, and other command can not be execute on time .

however, today i run the `keys *` on my db which has about 8million data.
and then i use my other client to exec other command like `get` or `set`, this all work well, and give response on time.

so, i'm confused that why my command `keys` not block.

the picture is https://i.stack.imgur.com/8flt4.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KEYS` (and almost any other Redis command for that matter) **is** blocking, do not be fooled :)

While Redis is scanning its internal dictionary and assembling the response, it is blocked. However, after the response is ready and moved to the network layer, the server is free to process the next operations. Your client, in the meanwhile, is blocked from the time it sent `KEYS` until the entire response is received by it.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: So the server should be blocked as long as `Keys *` is blocked as per the picture attached above? Because it has not reached the network layer yet as it is still scanning.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting fact about blocking commands is that they do not block the whole server, but just the client calling them. Source: https://redis.io/docs/reference/modules/modules-blocking-ops/